# Replacing a jQuery selected range of cells?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In the code below, let's call it `test.htm`, upon load I get rendered a table:

[image: ffox1]

Then, if I click on any of the header cells, a script runs that iterates over the table rows with the jQuery selector "`#mytable > tbody > tr`", and then it uses a chained filter, "`td:gt(0):lt(2)`", to select a range of `td` cells in each row. So, if our columns are indexed `0,1,2,3,4`, then `gt(0)` will select `1,2,3,4` - and the chained `lt(2)` will be applied to 0:`1`,1:`2`,2:`3`,3:`4`, and so only 0:`1`,1:`2` will remain, or in terms of original column indexes, `1,2` are selected.

To this selection, I want to toggle a class that changes background color, but I would also like to replace the content of the two cells. So I'm trying:

```
$( "td:gt(0):lt(2)", $thisRow ).toggleClass( "viol" );
$( "td:gt(0):lt(2)", $thisRow ).html("<td>AAAAA</td><td>BBBB</td>");
```

and the toggling of the class (standalone) works, but the replacement doesn't:

[image: ffox2]

So, instead of replacing the two cells with two other cells - I end up splitting *each* of the cells, because `.html()` gets applied to each element of the collection, and furthermore it changes the *inner* HTML of the element.

So, assuming in a row iteration loop, I have access to replacement strings like `<td>AAAAA</td><td>BBBB</td>` for a range of cells, how can I replace a range of cells with the content described by this HTML string? To be clear, in the context of this example I'd want the result to be:

[image: ffox3]

The code for `test.htm`:

```htm
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
  <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script> -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
.a1 {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  font-size: 1em;
  height:auto;
}
.viol { background-color: #DCE0FF; }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript">
function TableHeadListener(inevobj) {
  console.log("TableHeadListener", inevobj);
  ToggleTdRangeClass();
}
function ToggleTdRangeClass() {
  $('#mytable > tbody > tr').each(function() {
    $thisRow = $(this);
    $( "td:gt(0):lt(2)", $thisRow ).toggleClass( "viol" );
    $( "td:gt(0):lt(2)", $thisRow ).html("<td>AAAAA</td><td>BBBB</td>"); // AAA/BBB becomes html of each matched cell individually;!
  });
}
createTable = function() {
  var htmlTblString = '<table border="1" id="mytable">\n\
    <thead>\n\
      <tr>\n\
        <th>Row h, cell h1</th>\n\
        <th>Row h, cell h2</th>\n\
        <th>Row h, cell h3</th>\n\
        <th>Row h, cell h4</th>\n\
        <th>Row h, cell h5</th>\n\
      </tr>\n\
    </thead>\n\
    <tbody>\n\
      <tr>\n\
        <td>Row d1, cell d1-1</td>\n\
        <td>Row d1, cell d1-2</td>\n\
        <td>Row d1, cell d1-3</td>\n\
        <td>Row d1, cell d1-4</td>\n\
        <td>Row d1, cell d1-5</td>\n\
      </tr>\n\
      <tr>\n\
        <td>Row d2, cell d2-1</td>\n\
        <td>Row d2, cell d2-2</td>\n\
        <td>Row d2, cell d2-3</td>\n\
        <td>Row d2, cell d2-4</td>\n\
        <td>Row d2, cell d2-5</td>\n\
      </tr>\n\
    </tbody>\n\
  </table>\n';
  $("#content").html(htmlTblString);
  // add events:
  var mtb = $("#mytable");
  mtb.find('th').each(function() { $(this).on('click', null, this, TableHeadListener); });
}

ondocready = function() {
  createTable();
}
$(document).ready(ondocready);
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>

  <div id="content" class="a1"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I didn't understand what are you trying to do and what is your problem, can you be more clear or provide a fiddle?

Comment: @Shlomi Haver - what I'm trying to do, I wrote: "_I click on any of the header cells .... to select a range of td cells in each row. To this selection, I want to toggle a class that changes background color, but I would also like to replace the content of the two cells_"; my problem is that the content is not replaced, but instead _inserted in_ the cells. And there is a full HTML file which you can just copy/paste in a text file, call it `test.htm`, and open it in Firefox - if you have jQuery at the same location (I'll change it to online now), it will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you can do this is store the values you want on an `array[]` and then set it to each `td` element based on the order of the array. Check this:

```js
$('#mytable > tbody > tr').each(function() {
  var txt = ['AAAA','BBBB'],
      count = 0;
  $thisRow = $(this);
  $("td:gt(0):lt(2)", $thisRow).toggleClass("viol");
  $("td:gt(0):lt(2)", $thisRow).each(function(){
    $(this).html(txt[count]);
    count++
  })
});
```

```css
.a1 {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  font-size: 1em;
  height: auto;
}
.viol {
  background-color: #DCE0FF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" id="mytable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Row h, cell h1</th>
      <th>Row h, cell h2</th>
      <th>Row h, cell h3</th>
      <th>Row h, cell h4</th>
      <th>Row h, cell h5</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Row d1, cell d1-1</td>
      <td>Row d1, cell d1-2</td>
      <td>Row d1, cell d1-3</td>
      <td>Row d1, cell d1-4</td>
      <td>Row d1, cell d1-5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row d2, cell d2-1</td>
      <td>Row d2, cell d2-2</td>
      <td>Row d2, cell d2-3</td>
      <td>Row d2, cell d2-4</td>
      <td>Row d2, cell d2-5</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Many thanks @DaniP - I was hoping that I could have done the replacement in "one" go (i.e. I have the string overwrite the selection), but apparently that is not possible - your approach with arrays looks like the next best thing.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your major confusion is with iterating over each item in your jquery selector.  What you need is `each` https://api.jquery.com/each/

`each` allows allows you to access the element both as a paremeter and by index, giving you complete control of what content you'd like to replace and where.

```
$( "td:gt(0):lt(2)", $thisRow ).html("<td>AAAAA</td><td>BBBB</td>");
```

would be replaced with

```
$( "td:gt(0):lt(2)", $thisRow ).each(function (index, element) {
    if (index % 2 === 0) {
        element.html('BBBB');
    }
    else {
        element.html('AAAAA');
    }
});
```

or something similar.

Comment: Indeed, I didn't quite understand that since I have a range selection as a collection, I have to iterate over each element with `.each`; thanks for clarifying! I was otherwise hoping that I could just specify a range collection, and replace it with a string; turns out that is not quite possible.